UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U26'), dtype('float64')) -> None How to solve this error?
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [42], in <cell line: 1>()
1 for i in range(len(df)): ----> 2     path='./ODIR-5K/Training Images/'+df['filename'][i] 3     img=cv2.imread(path,0) 4     if df['filename'][i].split('_')[1].split('.')[0]=='left':
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U26'), dtype('float64')) -> None
for i in range(len(df)):
    path='./ODIR-5K/Training Images/'+df['filename'][i]
    img=cv2.imread(path,0)
    if df['filename'][i].split('_')[1].split('.')[0]=='left':
        img=cv2.rotate(img,cv2.cv2.ROTATE_180)  # rotating image left to 180 to get same side in modelling
    else:img=img
    x,y=np.nonzero(img)
    img=np.array(img[min(x):max(x)+1,min(y):max(y)+1])
    img=cv2.resize(img,(220,220),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    img=img.reshape(220,220,1)
    cropped_image=img[14:204,30:220]
    cropped_image=cropped_image/255.0
    df['filename'][i]=cropped_image

